# Dynamically render a sequence of divs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to display a set of divs in a sequence.

Currently I have a React class that maps over a JSON object array and outputs a set of inner divs, each set corresponding to an index in the objects.

here is the JSON, with objects space1 and space2, each with 3 indices:

```
  "Devotions": [
    {
      "space1": {
        "0": 1.0,
        "1": 0.0,
        "2": 3.0
      },
      "space2": {
        "0": 0.0,
        "1": 1.0,
        "2": 0.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this example, the react class is rendering the divs for the 0th, 1st and 2nd indices of each of the object:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Maps.css";
import df3 from "./data/df3.json";

class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = df3;
    this.state = data;
  }
  renderDiv = () => {
    var df4 = df3["Devotions"];
    return df4.map(v => {
      return Object.keys(v).map(host => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div
              className={host}
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Djakarta",
                color: "rgba(143, 0, 145,0.6)",
                margin: "27px",
                fontSize: "9px"
              }}
            >
              {host}
              <div
                className="d1"
                style={{
                  borderRadius: "50%",
                  transform: `scale(${v[host][0]},${v[host][0]})`,
                  opacity: "9%"
                }}
              >
                {v[host][0]}
              </div>
              <div
                className="d2"
                style={{
                  borderRadius: "50%",
                  transform: `scale(${v[host][1]},${v[host][1]})`,
                  opacity: "9%"
                }}
              >
                {v[host][1]}
              </div>
              <div
                className="d3"
                style={{
                  borderRadius: "50%",
                  transform: `scale(${v[host][2]},${v[host][2]})`,
                  opacity: "9%"
                }}
              >
                {v[host][2]}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div id="animap">{this.renderDiv()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Maps;
```

each div is connected to css (something like this; a working example is in the codepen)

```
.d1-d3 {
opacity:0%;
animation : d1-d3 animation;
animation duration: 3s;
}

.d1animation {
33%{opacity:9%}
}
.d1animation {
66%{opacity:9%}
}
.d1animation {
99%{opacity:9%}
}
```

So, im basically adding all of the divs manually, and giving each div a unique css class with a unique keyframe animation, and manually choreographing how they appear. This is clearly, not elegant.

***Is there a better way to dynamically render all of the divs in a sequence?***

As always, help is appreciated, and here is the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-bash-ndyjl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map`. And return one div with dynamic contnet

Codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-albattani-076j0?file=/src/App.js

```
          {Object.keys(v[host]).map((x, i) => (
            <div
              key={i}
              className={`d${i + 1}`}
              style={{
                borderRadius: "50%",
                transform: `scale(${v[host][x]},${v[host][x]})`,
                opacity: "9%"
              }}
            >
            {v[host][x]}
          </div>
        ))}
```

So finally:

```
renderDiv = () => {
var df4 = df3["Devotions"];
console.log(df4);
return df4.map(v => {
  return Object.keys(v).map(host => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className={host}
          style={{
            fontFamily: "Djakarta",
            color: "rgba(143, 0, 145,0.6)",
            margin: "27px",
            fontSize: "9px"
          }}
        >
          {host}
          {Object.keys(v[host]).map((x, i) => (
            <div
              key={i}
              className={`d${i + 1}`}
              style={{
                borderRadius: "50%",
                transform: `scale(${v[host][x]},${v[host][x]})`,
                opacity: "9%"
              }}
            >
              {v[host][x]}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
});
};
```

Comment: this is the one. Thanks Ashish!

Answer (score 1):

Use one div and loop through it, introduce an index variable.

Here is the demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-shadow-7j7dt?file=/src/App.js

```
 renderDiv = () => {
    var df4 = df3["Devotions"];
    return df4.map(obj => {
      return Object.keys(obj).map((key, i) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div
              key={key}
              className={key}
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Djakarta",
                color: "rgba(143, 0, 145,0.6)",
                margin: "27px",
                fontSize: "9px"
              }}
            >
              {key}
              <div
                key={key + i}
                className="d1"
                style={{
                  borderRadius: "50%",
                  transform: `scale(${obj[key][i]},${obj[key][i]})`,
                  opacity: "9%"
                }}
              >
                {obj[key][i]}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: this is not displaying the sequence as in my example :https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-bash-ndyjl? , rather it seems to be displaying only one step.